# Find if $f(x,y)=\left | x-y \right |$ is quasiconcave and quasiconvex?

Tags: convex-analysis

$$f(x,y)=\left | x-y \right |$$

Hello, Do we have to check for quasiconcavity using leel curves?
Or is there any other way?

I'm finding it very difficult to plot or imagine the level curves
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: "I'm finding it very difficult to plot" ?? The graph is simply a V-shape whose base is the line $x=y,z=0$. Convexity should follow trivially.

Comment: No, the level curves are straight lines parallel to each other

Comment: Indeed they are, hence, as I said, "The graph is simply a V-shape whose base..." and the answer to your question follows directly. (Why "No"?)

Comment: OH! I just imagined it in a sort of 3D graph. Since the level curves are spreading out it is convex?

Comment: Thankyou, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can see this function is the composition of the linear function $g(x,y)=x-y$ and the convex function $h(s)= |s|$. So it is Convex,let alone quasiconvex !

Answer (score 0):

If we show it is convex, it will imply its q-convexity.

Convexity condition: $$tf(x_1,y_1)+(1-t)f(x_2,y_2)\ge f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2,ty_1+(1-t)y_2) \Rightarrow$$

$$t|x_1-y_1|+(1-t)|x_2-y_2|\ge |tx_1+(1-t)x_2-ty_1-(1-t)y_2|=|t(x_1-y_1)+(1-t)(x_2-y_2)|.$$

This is true because of the triangle inequality: $$|x|+|y|\ge |x+y|.$$